# Slow Neo4j query on indexed DB

Tags: neo4j

Does anyone know why this query below would take  ~4900 ms  in the Neo4jShell. I have indexes on all the properties & less than 15,000 nodes & relationships. Only 1 result is returned

```
MATCH (oq:O { id: "some-id"})-->(pi:PI)-->(pd:PD { name: "some-name" })
WITH pi,oq LIMIT 1
MATCH pi-->(ll:O { lang:"en"  } ) ,  oq-->(pix:PI)-->(pdx:PD { name: "some-other-name" }),
      pix-->(abs:O { lang:"en"  } )
RETURN oq,pi,ll,pix,abs  LIMIT 200;
```

Comment: How many relationship types do you have? Unless you only have one, adding in relationship types should improve performance quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What do your indexes look like?

if you execute `schema` in the shell you should see:

index on :O(id) ONLINE;
index on :O(lang) ONLINE;
index on :PD(name) ONLINE;

can you profile your query in the neo4j shell? Just prepend it with the `PROFILE` keyword and add the output to your question.

Comment: neo4shell froze & I had to close the command window, before I read your msg. Whenever I rerun Neo4Shell, I get         Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase ; Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: C:\Users\blahblah\Documents\Neo4j\graph.db\store_lock. Please ensure n

Comment: ok, there was one property missing an index. Seems like its faster after adding an index on the missing one.